# Indexers(Smart array)

Tags: c#, console-application, indexer

Our Class Teacher had given us a Program on `Indexers()`,When i compiled and Execute the Program in my Computer i got error as

> Error:1 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and
>   'method group'

Why i am getting this error??...and Please Explain the Logic of the Program and Why Indexers are used and i am also getting 
Runtime Error
        Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
        collection.
        Parameter name: index

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections;
    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
            public object this[int index]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (index < 0 || index >= array.Count)
                    {
                        return (null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (array[index]);
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    array[index] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        class Demo
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p[0] = "123";
                p[1] = "abc";
                p[2] = "xyz";
                for (int i = 0; i <p.Count ; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you expect `p.Count` to come from?

Comment: @Jon: Strange that the error message calls `p.Count` a _method group_. `class Program` has no method `Count`.

Comment: What is p.Count? a method? If so, `i < p.Count()` may help.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, I thought that was odd too. But that's what the OP should at least look at.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ArrayList` anymore these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing because the compiler could not find a property named `Count`. Instead, it found a method—either one which isn't shown here, or if `Program` implements [`IEnumerable<object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), then it's likely Linq's [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method.

Try adding a `Count` property to `Program`

```
class Program
{
    ...

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.array.Count; }
    }
}
```

That will solve the compiler error. Now, if you want to know *why* it's using [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)… well I suppose because your teacher wanted to illustrate how they can be used. Indexers are just a bit of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) which just make writing code like `p.GetItem(i)` look cleaner, `p[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a Count implementation in you Program. Add the Count implementation and try to re-compile.

```
    class Program
    {
        ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

        public int Count { get { return array.Count; } }

        public object this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index < 0 || index >= array.Count)
                {
                    return (null);
                }
                else
                {
                    return (array[index]);
                }
            }
            set
            {
                array[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a Count Property and a constructor that initializes your ArrayList to the correct size, like this:

```
class Program
{
    ArrayList array = null;

    public Program(int size)
    {
        array = new ArrayList(size);
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= array.Count)
            {
                return (null);
            }
            else
            {
                return (array[index]);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            array[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return array.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whz did you tzpe all zour *Y*'s as *Z*'s?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Haha. Sorry, changed keyboard layout without noticing :-)